# Unable to get the bitmap from gallery with Intent.ACTION_PICK

Tags: android, bitmap, onactivityresult

I'm having a simple problem that may seem easy, however, when I pick a image from the gallery and try to set it up the in imageview in onActivityResult, the error would show up.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/35 }} to activity {com.mypackagename/com.mypackagename.SQLiteActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

This error must be due to the null object. That would mean that no data was retreived? I percieve that the settings that I made had no problem, however, I may have missed something. I've set the sample code below.

This is the code that calls the gallery

```
public void settingImage(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}
```

This code is for getting the results

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        // Log.d("Path", picturePath);
        //sampleimage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        // imgPath = picturePath;
        icontext.setText(picturePath);
        cursor.close();
    } else {

    }
}
```

Here's some settings

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
```

basic sdk setup

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 22
```

Comment: `icontext` is null, for this reason a NullPointerException is thrown. Where do you initialize it? Please post more code

Comment: Also, you said that you're trying to set it up in a `ImageView`, but you're using `TextView` on your code. Could you double check you're not just referencing the wrong object?

Comment: No, it means that your code in `onActivityResult()` is broken, particularly on modern Android devices. [A `Uri` is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html); you cannot transform a `Uri` into some file path reliably.

Comment: are u using contentresolver?

Comment: Yes, I'm using getContentResolver() . I tried to set the path string to the TextView, and set the bitmap into the ImageView. I'm using only some simple code like the one posted above. So I believe there is not so much other stuff that I can post.  Or is there some better solution that you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

I have try this to get Bitmap,

code that calls the gallery picker,

```
  Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
  photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
  startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

getting the results of bitmap,

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();                

                //yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                try {
                    yourSelectedImage = decodeUri(selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            //    imgViewProfilePic.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);                  
            }
    }
}
```

to decode uri,

```
private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 140;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            break;
        }
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);

}
```